# Retrieve Boolean value of 'isAVideo' Key in Parse

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, uiimageview, avfoundation

Users of my app can upload images or videos. If the user uploads a video, a still image representation is also uploaded to the @"images" column in parse. Those files populate a Table View of still images. 
I created a third column to manage a boolean value indicating if the object isAVideo (True or False).

In my Table View feedcell.m file I have a method to set the feed Item like so

```
- (void)setFeedItem:(PFObject *)feedItem
{
NSLog(@"setting feed item");
_feedItem = feedItem;

PFUser *user = [feedItem objectForKey:@"user"];
[_usernameButton setTitle:user.username
                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"tfeed"];

[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if (!object) {
        // Found nothing
    } else {
        BOOL isVideo = [[object objectForKey:@"isAVideo"]boolValue];
        if (isVideo == true) {
            NSLog(@"Object is a VIDEO");
            _pictureView.image = self.feedImage;
        // Create play button
        UIButton *playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [playButton addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(playVideo:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        // Set the play image
        UIImage *playImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"playButtonImage.pgn"];
        [playButton setImage:playImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        playButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 375);
        [_pictureView addSubview:playButton];
        [_pictureView bringSubviewToFront:playButton];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Object is not a video");
            _pictureView.image = self.feedImage;
        }
    }
}];
}
```

My goal is to add a play button when the object is a video, but the button is added to all objects regardless of it Bool value.

I think my query and/or conditional statement must be wrong.

EDIT: removed line:

```
[query whereKey:@"isAVideo" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you are querying for only objects where `isAVideo` is `YES` in this line: `[query whereKey:@"isAVideo" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];`, meaning that `if (isAVideo)` would always evaluate to `true`.

Comment: I do believe you are correct, but I don't know how to do what I am trying to achieve. I have never worked with parse.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know...what happens when that line gets removed?

Comment: When I remove that line, all objects behave like (isAVideo == false), yet I can see that I have a mix of both file types in parse.